# SDL in Xcode on MacMini M1 - Window not showing

Tags: xcode, macos, sdl

I know this is similar to some other posts but still a little different...
I'm using the newest version of Xcode with SDL. The following code should show me a window but nothing happens except that I get the following message: Metal API Validation Enabled
Program ended with exit code: 0
When I disable this validation nothing happens at all. Any ideas on what might be wrong?

`````
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    SDL_Init((SDL_INIT_VIDEO) <0);
    SDL_Window *window;
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Title", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN); //also tried different WINDOW_ input here
    if (window == NULL) {
            // In the case that the window could not be made...
            printf("Could not create window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
            return 1;
        }
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    SDL_Delay(3000);

}
````
`````

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but for a start, the `int main()` should be replaced with `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` and i'm not sure about `SDL_Init((SDL_INIT_VIDEO) <0);` just try `SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);` also, im not 100% about this I don't use mac, but if there are `.dll` on mac make sure you have the correct `.dll` files aswell (note what you're compiling (64bit or 32bit) use the corresponding `.dll` files)

Comment: Thank you. I will try. Not sure about .dll files. I need to do some research on that. I thought it might also have to do with the new M1 chip.... ... tried your recommendations but no, nothing happens.